# For loop time complexity up to different "i" control value

Tags: java, algorithm, for-loop, time, time-complexity

Which is the time complexity of the for loop, when the control parameter inside the loop has an increasement by +2?

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < n ; i = i + 2){
 //something
}
```

I understand that a simple for loop time complexity is N * (operations inside the loop). For example this one

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++){
     //something
    }
```

Also it can be written as MathSum (from i = start TO (end - start + 1)); in this case
MathSum(i = 0 to n-1+1)  * (something)

I guess the answear is also O(n).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is O(n) equal to O(2n)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19371489/why-is-on-equal-to-o2n)

Answer (score 0):

for(int i = 0 ; i < n ; i = i + 2){
}
Yes, The time complexity of the above for loop is also O(n) because it iterates n/2 times.
So the complexity will be O(n/2), in Complexity analysis, we remove the constant. So it will be O(n).

In complexity analysis, we don't calculate the exact time.