# Big O time complexity of LeetCode 567

Tags: python, time-complexity, big-o, sliding-window

Below is my solution of LeetCode 567. https://leetcode.com/problems/permutation-in-string/

What would the Big o time complexity of code below be?

Should it not be O(n*m) because of if (pattern_map == str_map): in code?

Edit: n = pattern_map, m = str_map
Edit 1: As stated is accepted answer, the correct values are n = length of s1 and m = length of s2.

I looked at this solution 10:00 mark (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6gRj_FH3MsA) and they seem to be using array. I am not sure it can be O(N) time complexity

```
class Solution:
        def checkInclusion(self, s1: str, s2: str) -> bool:
            
            pattern = s1
            str = s2
            
            pattern_map = {}
            str_map = {}
    
            for i in range(len(pattern)):
                patt_char = pattern[i]
                pattern_map[patt_char] = 1 + pattern_map.get(patt_char, 0)
    
            window_start = 0
            for i in range(len(str)):
                right_char = str[i]
                str_map[right_char] = 1 + str_map.get(right_char, 0)
    
                length_of_window = i-window_start+1
                if length_of_window == len(pattern):
                    left_char = str[window_start]
                    if (pattern_map == str_map):
                        return True
                    str_map[left_char] = str_map[left_char] - 1
    
                    if str_map[left_char] == 0:
                        del str_map[left_char]
    
                    window_start += 1
            
            return False
```

Comment: Can you say why you think it is this or that? In other words, try to solve it yourself first.

Comment: Above is my solution that I wrote. I wrote in the question my about my reasoning.

We have two dictionary. Comparing of two dict should be O(n). Since we have outer loop also in my code above. I think it should be O(n.m)

Comment: You don't even define what n and m is.

Comment: Shouldn't those be the sizes of those things? What else is there to say about them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's `O(n + m)`, where `n` is the length of `s1` and `m` is equal to the length of `s2`. (This time analysis assumes that the size of the alphabet is fixed at `26`, and that the `10^4` size bound on `s1` and `s2` are only to ensure that the code can be tested in a reasonable amount of time.)

The first `for` loop has `O(n)` iterations, and does a constant amount of work per iteration. So, its runtime is `O(n)`.

The second `for` loop has `O(m)` iterations. It does constant work per iteration. Notice that the dictionaries map between letters and their counts. However, the problem statement says that "`s1` and `s2` consist of lowercase English letters." The size of these dictionaries are bounded by a constant (26 keys at most, to be exact), so comparing them takes constant time. Everything else in the loop takes constant time. So this loop takes `O(m)` time.

Thus, the runtime is `O(n + m)`.

---

If we can't assume that the size of the alphabet is fixed as a constant (let `a` be the alphabet size), then each iteration of our second loop could take up to `O(a)` time. Then, our runtime would be bounded by `O(n + a * m)`.

Answer (score 0):

yes this would be like O(N+M), but for the sake of simplicity you could just say O(N)

Comment: You can't say that it's `O(n)`, because there's no check between the sizes of the strings.

Comment: i don't think it matters, it is still linear, is like when the time complexity is O(2N), you also would just say O(N). you can check this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19371489/why-is-on-equal-to-o2n/19371607 , or this wikipedia section https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Orders_of_common_functions you don't find O(something + otherthing)

Comment: The issue is that you don't know the size of `m`. This isn't an issue about constant factors.